# Cloud Build Error: "Unknown lifecycle phase "/root/.m2""

Tags: micronaut, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline with a Java Micronaut Application.

I'm using Cloud Build to build the Docker Image and ship it off to GCR

Locally, I used the following command to build the image and ship it off:

```
./mvnw deploy -Dpackaging=docker -Djib.from.image=openjdk -Djib.to.image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

This works all fine, very happy with this approach. The issue is putting this approach into the CI/CD pipeline.

Here is my `cloudbuild.yaml` config

```
steps:
  - id: "Build image and push to GCR"
    name: maven:3-jdk-8
    entrypoint: "./mvnw"
    args: [
      "deploy",
      "-Dpackaging=docker",
      "-Djib.from.image=openjdk",
      "-Djib.to.image=gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME:latest"
    ]
```

But I am getting the following error:

`[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "/root/.m2".`

Can anyone provide a bit of insight into how I can get around this error?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround in the end; or more so, a better solution.

In your pom file, add the following plugin:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <from>
            <image>openjdk</image>
          </from>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and then change the configuration of the `cloudbuild.yaml` to:

```
steps:
  - id: "Build image and push to GCR"
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn
    args:
      - "compile"
      - "jib:build"
      -  "-Dimage=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_IMAGE_NAME}:latest"
```

Hope this helps someone